# applying style to html dynamically from user input

Tags: php, html

I have a form that the user fills out with various items, including choosing a background. When they press a button to preview the form, I send them to another .php page which pops up an iframe and assembles all the form parts into a letter.  My problem is getting the background to populate. Here is how I am trying to get the background to display ($stationery is whatever the user asked for, with input cleaned up). I'm close, because if I cheat and code

```
<div style="width: 550px; height: 550px; padding: 15px; background-image:url(images/stationery/birthday.jpg);">
```

It works fine. But, as I said, that's cheating :-)

```
$final = "url(images/stationery/" . $stationery . ".jpg);" ; 
<div style="width: 550px; height: 550px; padding: 15px; background-image:" . $final .  ";>"
<h3>Message Preview</h3>
 .......
```

but the background doesn't show and I'm not getting any errors. Firebug however, looks horrendous:

```
<div <h3="" "="" ";="" $final;="" .="" background-image:\"="" 15px;="" padding:="" height:="" 550px;="" style="\"width:">
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$final = "url('images/stationery/" . $stationery . ".jpg');";
?>
<div style="width: 550px; height: 550px; padding: 15px; background-image: <?php print $final; ?>">
<h3>Message Preview</h3>
<!--Don't forget to close the div-->
</div>
```

Or if you want it all to be ran through the PHP interpreter:

```
<?php
$final = "url('images/stationery/" . $stationery . ".jpg');";
print '<div style="width: 550px; height: 550px; padding: 15px; background-image: ' . $final . '">';
print '<h3>Message Preview</h3>';
// Don't forget to close the div...
print '</div>';
?>
```

Better yet:

```
<div style="width: 550px; height: 550px; padding: 15px; background-image: url('images/stationery/<?php print $stationery; ?>.jpg');">
<h3>Message Preview</h3>
<!--Don't forget to close the div-->
</div>
```

Comment: worked great - I don't know why I was making it so complicated.  Thank you!